# Heroku: deploy jhipster project with `gitlab-ci` get crashed because of `Procfile` command

Tags: maven, spring-boot, heroku, jhipster, gitlab-ci

I had ask this issue on `jhipster-generator` Github issue before.
But still don't get solutions yet.

(See more at [Example Repository on my Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/w_nattasan/jhip-cicd-bug) and [Github issue#9426](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/9426))

I think it related to the final commands in the `Procfile` that I got from the generator which defined like these:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -Xmx256m -jar target/*.war --spring.profiles.active=prod,heroku,no-liquibase --server.port=$PORT 
release: cp -R src/main/resources/config config && ./mvnw liquibase:update -Pheroku
```

1. on `release:` the command `cp -R ...` can't be executed because from the last job of gitlab-ci which work fine and get green response. But when I see log in Heroku deploy instance, I got the `src/main/resource/config not found`. Then I try to investigate more with added `ls * -ltr` to `release:` and found that even `src` directory is not found. Only `target` directory is over there.
2. So I tried remove the `release:` row from `Procfile` the try again, then I got crashed messages from Heroku server running the application.

   - Some part from Log

```
2019-03-26T03:18:10.547189+00:00 app[web.1]: 03:18:10.536 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
2019-03-26T03:18:10.547217+00:00 app[web.1]: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.cache.spi.CachingProvider: Provider org.redisson.jcache.JCachingProvider not a subtype
...
2019-03-26T03:18:10.567009+00:00 app[web.1]: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
```

But if I run with the command `jhipster heroku` it will deploy with different method from the command defined in `.gitlab-ci.yml` file. And can be run successfully.

So due to the [Heroku deployment documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java-applications-with-the-heroku-maven-plugin) which I think it is the most related to the issue I found right now, what should I fix on the `Procfile` to get the final deployment on Heroku can work as it should be?

Any help will be appreciate and thank you in advance.

Comment: Same here. Did you find out anything yourself already? In my case, I deployed by uploading the .war directly (`heroku war:deploy build/libs/*war`) instead of doing a `git push heroku`, which gave other problems.

Comment: @JeroenKransen I found solution, will post later. But the point is the template code cannot run now, and need to change on `application.yml` config files and environment variables.

Comment: Could be useful for others. I got the `git push heroku` method working by now.

Answer (score 0):

[TLDR](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/9426#issuecomment-491574067);

I do these things and then the CI-CD with `Gitlab` -> `Heroku` can do CI-CD properly.

at `Procfile`, remove the `release:` line, because what the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file do when `deploy-to-production` state was performed is deploy the `JAR` file, not include the whole project directories, so, it's not important to copy files from project's directories anymore.

Now you can run CI-CD with all green on `Gitlab` pipeline and `Deployed succeed` on `Heroku`

But there are some issues will block your app from running properly. And here what I found.

```
# ===================================================================
# Spring Boot configuration for the "heroku" profile.
#
# This configuration overrides the application.yml file.
# ===================================================================

# ===================================================================
# Standard Spring Boot properties.
# Full reference is available at:
# http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html
# ===================================================================

eureka:
    instance:
        hostname: jhip-cicd-bug.herokuapp.com
        non-secure-port: 80
        prefer-ip-address: false

spring:
    datasource:
        type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
        url: ${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}
        username: ${JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME}
        password: ${JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD}
        hikari:
            maximumPoolSize: 8
    data:
        jest:
            uri: ${BONSAI_URL}
```

- The `application-heroku.yml` file, the reference to environment variables `${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}`, `${JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME}`, `${JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD}`, is not created, only thing be created is `DATABASE_URL` that contains with `postgres://[generated-user]:[generated-secret]@[generated-url]:5432/[generated-dbname]`
- It's wrong on

  - Not started with `jdbc:`
  - Environment variable name is different as defined above `DATABASE_URL` (created) not equals to `JDBC_DATABASE_URL`, and the `${JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME}`, `${JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD}` were not created. Then my workaround is create those environment variables on `Heroku` settings -> Config vars and edit their value properly, like...
  - key `JDBC_DATABASE_URL` value `jdbc:postgres://[url]:5432/[dbname]`
  - key `JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME` value `[username]`
  - key `JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD` value `[password]`
  - Or you might change this `url: ${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}` to `url: jdbc:${DATABASE_URL}` (never try before, not confident for the result).